# iis 7 turning off detailed error reporting causes classic asp error

Tags: iis-7, error-reporting

I am stumped as to why this is happening.

When I turn detailed error reporting off, I get internal server error. When I turn it on my page loads fine.

Has anyone ever come across this sort of thing before?

Comment: did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your script does have an error being raised somewhere and the error is being hidden somewhere in your HTML.

On the page in question, turn on detailed errors again, browse to the page then do a *View Source* in your browser and I bet you'll find there's something in there that shouldn't be, but not being rendered by the browser.

For example:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <% Response.Write "Just fine" %>
    <div id="noSnapshots" style="display:none">
    <table>

       <tr>
        <% Some error %>
        <td>table cell</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I turn on detailed errors in IIS the HTML above appears to render just fine but if I turn them off I get the red, white and grey `500 - Internal server error.` page.

Look either of these strings:

> *An error occurred on the server when processing the URL*

or

> *Microsoft VBScript runtime*

This is assuming you haven't altered the `Script Error Message` in the site's ASP feature pane.

Comment: hi kev, thanks for your input and appologies for my total lack of reply, i didnt even notice your answer.

Comment: basically it was an external pdf creation object error that somehow crashed the page with detailed error reports off, but was ok with.  I removed it and the page was fine both ways.  So i fixed the bug and all is good now. thanks for your reply.